# I am receiving a page Error500 on my CRUD pages

Tags: symfony, heroku, deployment, easyadmin

Am having an error 500 on one of my pages on my website. Its is a CRUDController in easyadmin and it is a Symfony application.
With the heroku logs i get :

2023-12-14T11:18:15.266498+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.180 - - [14/Dec/2023:11:18:15 +0000] "GET /admin?crudAction=index&crudControllerFqcn=App%5CController%5CAdmin%5CVinylCrudController HTTP/1.1" 500 101
1 "http://gpuppy-vinyl-ce7c530d2c4f.herokuapp.com/admin?crudAction=index&crudControllerFqcn=App%5CController%5CAdmin%5CArtistCrudController" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
2023-12-14T11:18:15.267007+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin?crudAction=index&crudControllerFqcn=App%5CController%5CAdmin%5CVinylCrudController" host=gpuppy-vinyl-ce7c530d2c4f.heroku
app.com request_id=f6ecfd1e-3a7a-4ac9-bb3d-43bcf9d5366f fwd="92.131.246.104" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=1307 protocol=http.

My APP_ENV = prod
I've got my procfile and my buildpacks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWwY5.png)

What is weird is that the associated controller works.
I've tried for a long time to correct it but its not working. Please help

I tried to change update symfony 6.1 to 6.4, changed a few lines in the Crud and associtated CRUD pages

Comment: Please attach output of symfony log.

Comment: Do you have tried to enable the dev mode?

Comment: Ok will try kasali

Comment: dev mode doesn't work :( at all

Comment: Look at your PHP error logs to see what PHP is complaining about. Alternately from a terminal what is the entire output when you run bin/console cache:clear

Comment: Hi and Happy New Year to everyone. I did a cache clear and it says [OK] Cache for the "prod" environment (debug=false) was successfully cleared.

Comment: GET /admin?crudAction=index&crudControllerFqcn=App%5CController%5CAdmin%5CVinylCrudController HTTP/1.1" 500 101
1 "http://gpuppy-vinyl-ce7c530d2c4f.herokuapp.com/admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/105.0.0.0
at=info method=GET path="/admin?crudAction=index&crudControllerFqcn=App%5CController%5CAdmin%5CVinylCrudController" host=gpuppy-vinyl-ce7c530d2c4f.heroku
app.com request_id=6c42d5c0-13c7-4f49-81af-fc7f739822a8 fwd="92.131.246.104" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=214ms status=500 bytes=1307 protocol=ht

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my question, i the logs there was a message :

```
{"message":"Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: \"When using date/time fields in EasyAdmin backends, you must install and enable the PHP Intl extension, which is used to format date/time values.
```

The Intl extension was already installed and enabled, so what I did is I added `ext-intl` in the `require` of the `composer.json`:

```
"require": 
        "ext-intl": "*",
```

Then

```
composer update
```

Now it works.